# Pass javascript function as parameter and evaluate its content as class content

Tags: javascript, oop, class, methods, parameters

Is it possible to pass a function as parameter to a method and evaluate it's content as if it was part of the class?

```
function Class()
{
    this.Method = function( param )
    {
        // Call "CallThis"
    };

    this.CallThis = function()
    {

    };
}

var c = new Class();
c.Method(
    {
        evalThisContent: function()
        {
            this.CallThis();
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow your intention:

```
function Class()
{
    this.Method = function( param, name )
    {
        this[name] = param;
        param.call(this);
    };

    this.CallThis = function()
    {

    };
}

var c = new Class();

c.Method(function() {
    this.CallThis();
}, 'evalThisContent');
```

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible to invoke the function, in this case with

```
param()
```

as for "as if it was part of the class", if you mean would it have access to its members through `this`, no it wouldn't. But you could pass in a reference to this (object of type Class) to the function and it could access its members through this reference.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the class in the way I think you may have intended, though Zirak seems to have already demonstrated the main idea.

```
function Class() {
}
Class.prototype.method = function(param) {
    if (typeof param === 'object' && param.evalThisContent) {
        param.evalThisContent.call(this);
    }
};
Class.prototype.callThis = function() {
    alert("I'm getting called indirectly!");
};

var c = new Class();
c.method(
    {
        evalThisContent: function()
        {
            this.callThis();
        }
    }
);
```

If you wish, you could instead add or alter "evalThisContent" dynamically on the prototype, making it available to all objects which may henceforth wish to call it:

```
Class.prototype.method = function(param) {
    if (typeof param === 'object' && param.evalThisContent && !Class.prototype.evalThisContent) {
        Class.prototype.evalContent = param.evalThisContent;
    }
    this.evalContent();
};
```

This has the advantage of not creating a function into memory each time, nor invoking it in a less than optimal way with `call`, while `call` (or `apply`), as in the first example, has the more commonly useful advantage of allowing each instance of the Class to use its own functions or implementations (or you could use inheritance).